# How to remove faucet handles

Tags: bathroom, leak, faucet

I have a dripping bathroom faucet and I cannot figure out how to remove the handles to replace the cartridge.  All videos I've seen on the internet show a screw to remove, but I popped off the top of the handle and I don't see any screw.  Here is a video of what it looks like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-9pmfznykY

And here are some pics from above and below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.  The lower part of the handle unscrews (the bell shaped part).  It was on pretty tight and hard to grip so I had to use an oil filter wrench.  And I had to use pliers to grip underneath to prevent the entire thing from spinning.